# How to add jars / dependecies via gradle in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: android, jar, intellij-idea, gradle

I don't have any experience in MAVEN, gradle or anyother build system. I'm working in Android Studio basically and I want to add few jars (and also their source). But the jars are hosted in maven repo. I can download the jars and directly add to the lib/ folder. But then, I don't know how to attach the sources. So what is the correct way to find add those jars via gradle in Android Studio? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure maven repo:

```
repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
}
```

Then add appropriate dependencies in:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.guava:guava:17.0-rc2'//e.g.
}
```

Comment: Ok, don't know NBS structure exactly but looks well. Add a dependency on the desired level.

Comment: The build fails after I add the `zxing` dependency. But works if I add it as external lib. Are their any good tutorials for Gradle, for a complete beginner like me?

Comment: What fails exactly? It's here: http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide.html

Comment: Thanks. Also, for another repo, I got similar error http://i.imgur.com/U9Q2n2c.png

Comment: Can You paste the `build.gradle` file?

Comment: Ok.. In `buildscript` section You configure `script` not project dependencies. Read the tutorial please, it's the best place to start.